# "The dll is not allowed to be included or could not be found" while building unity3d SignalR

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, asp.net-core-signalr

I'm using unity 2017.2 and ran into this error while building for APK file

```
ArgumentException: The Assembly System.Reflection.Emit is referenced by 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Core 
('Assets/Plugins/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Core.dll'). But the dll is not 
allowed to be included or could not be found.
UnityEditor.AssemblyHelper.AddReferencedAssembliesRecurse (System.String 
assemblyPath, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] alreadyFoundAssemblies, 
System.String[] allAssemblyPaths, System.String[] foldersToSearch, 
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[TKey,TValue] cache, 
UnityEditor.BuildTarget target) (at 
C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/AssemblyHelper.cs:152)
UnityEditor.AssemblyHelper.FindAssembliesReferencedBy (System.String[] paths, 
System.String[] foldersToSearch, UnityEditor.BuildTarget target) (at 
C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/AssemblyHelper.cs:192)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
```

My project need to use .Net 4.6. So, I have changed it in player setting. I don't have any error when I click play in the editor but when I want to build it, this is where it fail.

Hopefully someone can help me on this. Thank you

Comment: Do you want to run a server or the client? Because Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Core is only needed on the server side.

Comment: I want to run the client. Then, I need to delete this dll from my asset?

Comment: No, You just need `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client` and it will pull all the dependencies. It will not pull Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Core because it's for the server.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try it out. Will let you know the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution to this question in another thread.

You can find it in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47454259/signalr-unity3d-connection).

Hopefully someone can benefit from my answer.